# Cannot persist IsolatedStorageSettings data (C#)

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm developing a windows phone 8 application, which relies on IsolatedStorageSettings for saving application settings. I don't own a real device, so i'm using the emulator to test the app. Application settings persist correctly during the whole application lifecycle, even when you quit the application by navigating to the Windows Phone 8 start page and re-run it.
Application settings don't persist if i close the emulator and re-run the app.

The question is: would application settings persist correctly in a real device after it has been turned off?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. IsolatedStorage is persistent across power on/ off cycles of the device. The Application settings or IsolatedStorage is cleared only when the user removes(uninstalls) the app from the device.